can read only 16 bit wav file but recieved 32 - Tensorflow
I have converted all my wav files to 16 bit PCM and checked using below code
import soundfile as sf
ob = sf.SoundFile('./data/road.wav')
print('Sample rate: {}'.format(ob.samplerate))
print('Channels: {}'.format(ob.channels))
print('Subtype: {}'.format(ob.subtype_info))

But still when i call
history = my_model.fit(train_ds,
                       validation_data=valid_ds, epochs=20)

Got the following error
 tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Can only read 16-bit WAV files, but received 32
     [[{{node DecodeWav}}]]
     [[Func/StatefulPartitionedCall/input_control_node/_2/_7]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Can only read 16-bit WAV files, but received 32
     [[{{node DecodeWav}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

How to resolve this error? how to check if a wav is 32 bit?
